# Fabric causes errors when testers try download app

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, fabric-beta

My testers have problem with an app I had uploaded to Fabric Beta. During normal testing they uninstall already installed app from their devices and they download new version from Fabric. In that case everything works fine. App will download and launch properly.

Problems begins when they want to test situation when future app's users update my app from AppStore. My testers want to check if updated app will not crash.

Test case is easy:

1. List item
2. Download app from AppStore.
3. Launch it.
4. Download new version from Fabric (new version should override old)
5. Launch it.
6. App should not crash.

Problem appears in (4), Fabric shows error "download problem detected". (Note that everything works if there is no old app on device.).

Fabric has problems with overriding apps?

Fabric (1.7.7)
iOS 11
iPhone 6s Plus

PS. This test is important. Crash will appears when I change database model without migration for example.

Comment: You must migration data first. Because of you update using new db, but in older version, has another database version. So it will be crash

Comment: I know how to fix db crash. The question is about problem with overriding installation beta from Fabric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Paul from Fabric here. Did you uninstall the App Store version of your app first? Since iOS 9, Apple changed its policy to prevent apps from being installed over the existing App Store version by 3rd parties, so you need to delete the original app before installing the Beta version. For more information, see our docs here: https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/tester-experience.html.

Answer (score 2):

And the other reason could be if any other app is installing or updating parallelly, Fabric will not be able to install. Just faced the issue :)